# TypeScript class generic constraint

Tags: typescript

When constraining a generic type for a class, ts complains that the generic could be instantiated with a different subtype. Anyone have any idea what that actually means (and what to do about it)?

Reproduction (TypeScript 3.6.4):

```
interface BaseSchema {
  readonly id: string;
}

class Model<GenericSchema extends BaseSchema> {
  public test(): GenericSchema {
    return { id: '' };
  }
}
```

Error:

> Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GenericSchema'.   '{
>   id: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type
>   'GenericSchema', but 'GenericSchema' could be instantiated with a
>   different subtype of constraint 'BaseSchema'.ts(2322)

Seems to be related to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types

I can make it work with a type assertion, but it does not seem right:

```
interface BaseSchema {
  readonly id: string;
}

export class Model<GenericSchema extends BaseSchema> {
  public test2(): GenericSchema {
    return { id: '' } as GenericSchema;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: New example below. In the example we provide a generic MySchema when instantiating Model, and this expect the test() method to return MySchema.

```
class Model<
  GenericSchema extends {
    readonly id: string;
  }
> {
  public test() {
    const dbResult: GenericSchema = { id: '' };
    return dbResult;
  }
}

interface MySchema {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly name: string;
}

const model = new Model<MySchema>();
const schema: MySchema = model.test();
```

These are all contrived examples, the real use case is to access a DB and return data for which I have type annotations. Essentially MySchema would represent the data model in the database, so I want to provide it as a generic (since TS can't possibly know what the data looks like in the DB otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

```
interface BaseSchema {
  readonly id: string;
}

class Model<GenericSchema extends BaseSchema> {
  public test(): GenericSchema {
    return { id: '' };
  }
}

interface MySchema extends BaseSchema {
   readonly name: string;
}

var model = new Model<MySchema>();
var schema = model.test();
```

Does `test` return a `MySchema`? Well there's no `name` property, so no, it returns `BaseSchema`. Essentially that is what the error is trying to tell you in a somewhat roundabout way. The return type of `test` should be `BaseSchema` since the only property it has is `id` and you can't guarantee you'll return any particular subtype of it.

> Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GenericSchema'.

True, `GenericSchema` could have any number of properties, we have no idea of its shape.

> '{ id: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'GenericSchema'

In other words `{ id: string; }` *can* be assigned to `BaseSchema`.

> but 'GenericSchema' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseSchema'

`GenericSchema` could be anything that extends `BaseSchema`, how do we guarantee we're returning a type that isn't known to us?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. MySchema is never used in your example, did you mean `var model = new Model<MySchema>();`?

Comment: Got it. Hmm, I'm missing something here. With your example I was expecting `var model = new Model<MySchema>();` to complain since MySchema does not include the required `id` field. But it doesn't...

Comment: `interface MySchema extends BaseSchema` - If an interface _extends_ another interface it behaves just like a class extending another class, i.e. there's no need to redefine properties, unlike when a class _implements_ an interface.

Comment: I just updated my question with another example, does that example/reasoning make any sense?

Comment: Note by Ryan Cavanaugh (development lead for the TypeScript team)  https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1121995986862084096

Answer (score 2):

Maybe tweaking some of the names will help with the concept of generics. You should always prefix generic type identifiers with `T` to make it obvious what they are. (In this case I chose `TSchema`, but you could also use just `T`)

**The reason it gives an error is because TSchema can be ANYTHING in the universe that extends BaseSchema. And `{ id: '' }` absolutely does not fulfill "everything".**

```js
interface BaseSchema {
  id: string;
}

class Model<TSchema extends BaseSchema> {
  public test() {
    const dbResult: TSchema = { id: '' };
    return dbResult;
  }
}
```

You can't just create an object with an ID and claim it is of type `T`, as you can create any interface/class you want that extends `BaseSchema`. The only assumption you can make is that it extends `BaseSchema`.

---

If you just want a way to access data and return it with the correct type, then the result from the service (data access or HTTP or anything else) should return either a typed value or any value that can be casted. If that is the case there is nothing wrong with direct casting as you can assume it came back from the database in the right format (just make sure you validate models before saving to the database!).

**Simple Example:**

```js
interface BaseSchema {
  readonly id: string;
}

class Model<T extends BaseSchema> {

  private svc: SomeService;

  public constructor(private table: string) {
  }

  public get(id: string): T {
    return this.svc.getItemFromTableWithId(this.table, id) as T;
  }

  public getAll(): T[] {
    return this.svc.getAllFromTable(this.table) as T[];
  }

}

interface BlogArticle extends BaseSchema {
  name: string;
  author: string;
  lastUpdated: Date;
  published: boolean;
}

const blogArticles = new Model<BlogArticle>('blog-articles');

blogArticles.get(4); // Returns an instance of `BlogArticle`.
blogArticles.getAll(); // Returns an instance of `BlogArticle[]`.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here is an example of what I really want to do https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/39358 The Collection type takes a generic Schema. This schema is then the return type of collection.findOne().

Comment: For even more details, see this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/typesmongodb-336-type-error-onshs

Comment: @MikaelLirbank Thanks for pointing those to me. That is definitely a bug in TypeScript, so good catch! In that event I think the second method from the codesandbox is ideal: `return this.collection.findOne({ _id: id } as Schema);` In this case you can at least enforce that it has the properties of `Schema`.